# How do I make these relative imports work in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, relative-path

I have a directory structure that looks like this:

```
project/
        __init__.py
        foo/
            __init.py__
            first.py
            second.py
            third.py
        plum.py
```

In `project/foo/__init__.py` I import classes from `first.py`, `second.py` and `third.py` and put them in `__all__`.

There's a class in `first.py` named `WonderfulThing` which I'd like to use in `second.py`, and want to import by importing `*` from `foo`. (It's outside of the scope of this question why I'd like to do so, assume I have a good reason.)

In `second.py` I've tried `from .foo import *`, `from foo import *` and `from . import *` and in none of these cases is `WonderfulThing` imported. I also tried `from ..foo import *`, which raises an error "Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package".

I've read the docs and the PEP, and I can't work out how to make this work. Any assistance would be appreciated.

**Clarification/Edit:** It seems like I may have been misunderstanding the way `__all__` works in packages. I was using it the same as in modules,

```
from .first import WonderfulThing
__all__ = [ "WonderfulThing" ]
```

but looking at the docs again it seems to suggest that `__all__` may only be used in packages to specify the names of modules to be imported by default; there doesn't seem to be any way to include anything that's not a module.

Is this correct?

A non-wildcard import failed (`cannot import name WonderfulThing`). Trying `from . import foo` failed, but `import foo` works. Unfortunately, `dir(foo)` shows nothing.

Comment: Does it work without the wildcard import? (I.e., can you import WonderfulThing explictly?) Relative imports can be tricky on their own. I'd suggest that you make sure that's working before moving on to __all__.

Comment: `__all__` can contain the names of any objects. They don't have to be (and usually aren't) only modules.

Comment: "Unfortunately, dir(foo) shows nothing."
Nothing!? For me it shows `['WonderfulThing', '__all__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', 'first']`

You must be doing something fundamentally wrong, or you aren't showing us the actual code, because what you describe works just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: I did misunderstand the question: No `__all__` is not restricted to just modules.

One question is why you want to do a relative import. There is nothing wrong with doing `from project.foo import *`, here. Secondly, the `__all__` restriction on foo won't prevent you from doing `from project.foo.first import WonderfulThing`, or just `from .first import WonderfulThing`, which still will be the best way.

And if you really want to import a a lot of things, it's probably best to do `from project import foo`, and then use the things with `foo.WonderfulThing` instead for doing an `import *` and then using `WonderfulThing` directly.

However to answer your direct question, to import from the `__init__` file in second.py you do this:

```
from . import WonderfulThing
```

or

```
from . import *
```