# Python 3.4 importing a util class from another directory

Tags: python, import, python-3.4, subdirectory

I have a folder structure as below and I want to import a class from Util1.py into Impl1.py but cannot figure out how to write the Import function. I have seen the mention of PYTHONPATH but cannot completely figure out how to write the details around it. Any help is appreciated

```
Root folder
 |---Util
     |---Src
         |--Util1.py
         |--Util2.py
 |---Impl1
     |---Src
         |--Impl1.py
         |--Impl2.py
```

Some information - I am using Python3.4. Please let me know what other information I can provide to help assist you guys help answer my question

Comment: do you want to import Impl1 into Util1 ? or vice versa?. It isn't clear in the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to handle this is to structure your project into packages, then use relative imports.  (There are a ton of questions on here about how to do this, for example: [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16637428/relative-import-in-python-3-not-working), [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581260/how-do-i-make-these-relative-imports-work-in-python-3?rq=1).

The [kludge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kludge) method that may be necessary if you can't restructure your code is to dynamically add the directory containing your "other" code to your PATH.

For example, assuming you're inside `Impl1.py` and want to call the `foo` function inside `Util1.py`, you could do:

```
# Get parent of parent
import os, sys
pp = os.path.realpath(__file__)
for _ in range(3): pp = os.path.dirname(pp)
# Add np to path
sys.path.append(os.path.join(pp, 'util', 'src'))

# Import file
import Util1

# Call function
Util1.foo()
```

Comment: When you say "pp = os.path.realpath(__file__)". The __file__ is the complete path to the Util1.py like /home/<user>/workspace/Root/Utils/src/Util1.py

Comment: Okay, so then you're inside Util1.py trying to get somewhere else -- update the arguments to `join`, and the `import` appropriately.  `pp` is initialized to that path , then the next line goes 3 directories up (Src, Util, Root)

Answer (score 0):

you can use relative import e.g

For example to import a class 'foo' from Util1.py into Impl1 you can write this in Impl1.py

```
from ../../Util/Src/Util1 import foo
```

Further reading : https://stackoverflow.com/a/12173406/2073920